# Adding two values at regular time intervals until they pass another value

Tags: algorithms

Having trouble figuring out an equation or what this is even called.

We want a sum S to be >= Z

We have two values. A and B.

S starts as A+B.

Every X amount of time (Minutes/seconds/milliseconds etc.) A is added.

Every Y amount of time B is added.

If A = 200 and B = 250. X = 2 and Y = 3. Z = 2000. I want to be able to figure out how long it takes for S to be >= 2000.

At a time of zero S = 450. At 2 seconds A gets added to make it 650. 3 seconds B gets added so it's 900. 4 seconds A is added again for 1100. At 6 seconds both A and B are added for 1550. 8 seconds A is added for 1750. 9 Seconds B is added for 2000. In this case 9 seconds is what I'm looking for as the solution.

And to be clear I'm looking for help with understanding the sort of equation I need to solve these sorts of problems. The values I gave are just an example, but I'd like to be able to plug in the values for A + B and the time intervals they are added at to get something that'll output a value where they cross a final variable.

Answer (score 1):

$S$ as a function of time $t$ is $S = A + B + \left(A\lfloor\frac{t}{X}\rfloor+B\lfloor\frac{t}{Y}\rfloor\right)$.

This function is, strictly speaking, not invertible over its whole domain. If all of the variables are assumed to be integral, then finding an exact $t$ given a valid value for $S$ is a linear Diophantine problem and can be solved with a recursive algorithm but has no arithmetically closed-form solution.

A recursive solution is availbale even if the variables are not all integral. The most practical way is to approximate $S = A+B+\left(\frac{A}{X}+\frac{B}{Y}\right)t$, invert for $t = \left[\frac{S - (A+B)}{\left(\frac{A}{X}+\frac{B}{Y}\right)}\right]$, and substitute the result back into the above equation for $S$. If the resulting value is lower than the given $S$, then increase $t$. If it is higher, then decrease $t$. Repeat until the calculated value for $S$ matches the given value for $S$.

You can speed up the process, particularly if $X$ and $Y$ are both large, by skipping any values of $t$ that divide to neither $X$ nor $Y$.

For your given values of:

- S = 2000
- A = 200
- B = 250
- X = 2 seconds
- B = 3 seconds

You have $t = 8$ seconds initially, which recursively is increased to 9 for the final result.

There is probably an easy way to show bounds on the error and possibly even to correct the equation for $t$ to reduce the amount of recursion needed, if you can assume that all of the variables are natural or integral. For the given values of $X$ and $Y$, the correct value for $t$ is always the initial estimate, or that plus 1.

---

$\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ and $[\,\cdot\,]$ are the floor and rounding functions respectively.

Comment: I don't think that's exactly what I'm looking for. For example if I plug things in to the first equation. S comes out as 2100, when it should be 2000. Also plugging things into the inverted equation it's spitting out t as 8.45.

Comment: The system you described never reaches exactly 2000, it skips straight to 2100. Please modify your description of the system if this is not its actual behavior. Additionally, the ceilling function was added specifically because this is a discretization of a continuous function. 8.45 is not the output of the above function, it is 9.

Comment: It should hit 2000 at 9 seconds. I chose this example partly because it's easy to calculate by hand. Assuming I didn't make a mistake writing it out. It starts at 450. hits 650 (+200) at 2 seconds, 900(+250) at 3 seconds, 1100 (+200) at 4 seconds, 1550 (+200 and +250) at 6 seconds, 1750 (+200) at 8 seconds and then finally 2000 (+250) at 9 seconds. I'm not sure how to exactly describe it since I'm not fluent in math terminology. The sum is being fed by two values and each value has an independent time interval where it gets added.

Comment: You're right, sorry. I've updated the equation for S to be exact. Working on an improved equation for t now.

Comment: Answer is now updated.